# Combine separate arrays in multiple loops?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I have a nested bookings data with multi arrays, objects like this. I need to get the ticket's arrays and combine/concast in to one array.

```
[
    {
      "cinema": [
        {
          "tickets": [
            {
              "maLichChieu": "19987",
              "maRap": "539",
              "tenRap": "Rạp 9",
              "ngayChieuGioChieu": "2019-01-01T10:10:00",
              "giaVe": 75000,
              "thoiLuong": 120
            },
            {
              "maLichChieu": "19988",
              "maRap": "539",
              "tenRap": "Rạp 9",
              "ngayChieuGioChieu": "2019-01-01T12:10:00",
              "giaVe": 75000,
              "thoiLuong": 120
            }
          ],
          "url": "cgv-1",
          "cinemaName": "CGV-1",
        }
      ],
      "name": "CGV",
    },
    {
      "cinema": [
        {
          "tickets": [
            {
              "maLichChieu": "33805",
              "maRap": "795",
              "tenRap": "Rạp 5",
              "ngayChieuGioChieu": "2019-01-01T10:10:00",
              "giaVe": 75000,
              "thoiLuong": 120
            },
            {
              "maLichChieu": "33806",
              "maRap": "795",
              "tenRap": "Rạp 5",
              "ngayChieuGioChieu": "2019-01-01T12:10:00",
              "giaVe": 75000,
              "thoiLuong": 120
            }
          ],
          "url": "glx",
          "cinemaName": "GLX",
        }
      ],
      "name": "Galaxy",
    }
  ]
```

So I have the code:

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.bookings.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < this.bookings[i].cinema.length; j++) {
        console.log(this.bookings[i].cinema[j].tickets);
        // I want to combine/concat 2 arrays in to one here
      }
    }
```

How to write the concat/combine part to make it works correctly? Or is there any better code to do this? Is code below correct without missing data?

```
this.bookings[i].cinema[j].tickets.concat(this.bookings[i].cinema[j + 1].tickets);
```

You can check code here https://jsfiddle.net/8kcohqx3/

Thank you for help

Comment: do you want your output to be as follows?
```
[
  {
    "maLichChieu": "19987",
    "maRap": "539",
    "tenRap": "Rạp 9",
    "ngayChieuGioChieu": "2019-01-01T10:10:00",
    "giaVe": 75000,
    "thoiLuong": 120
  },
  {
    "maLichChieu": "19988",
    "maRap": "539",
    "tenRap": "Rạp 9",
    "ngayChieuGioChieu": "2019-01-01T12:10:00",
    "giaVe": 75000,
    "thoiLuong": 120
  },
  {
    "maLichChieu": "33805",
     (...remaining fields)
  },
  {
    "maLichChieu": "33806",
      (...remaining fields)
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to create an empty result array at the beginning and using that to concat with the current ticket array. That way you don't need to care about array boundaries.

```
let result = [];

for (let i = 0; i < this.bookings.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < this.bookings[i].cinema.length; j++) {
    result = result.concat(this.bookings[i].cinema[j].tickets);
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it very concisely with ES10 `Array.prototype.flatMap`:

```
const results = data.flatMap(record => record.cinema.flatMap(i => i.tickets));
```

but it might require adding `es2019` to your `lib` field in `tsconfig.json`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use flatMap

```
  const test = [{
      "cinema": [{
        "tickets": [{
            "maLichChieu": "19987",
            "maRap": "539",
            "tenRap": "Rạp 9",
            "ngayChieuGioChieu": "2019-01-01T10:10:00",
            "giaVe": 75000,
            "thoiLuong": 120
          },
          {
            "maLichChieu": "19988",
            "maRap": "539",
            "tenRap": "Rạp 9",
            "ngayChieuGioChieu": "2019-01-01T12:10:00",
            "giaVe": 75000,
            "thoiLuong": 120
          }
        ],
        "url": "cgv-1",
        "cinemaName": "CGV-1",
      }],
      "name": "CGV",
    },
    {
      "cinema": [{
        "tickets": [{
            "maLichChieu": "33805",
            "maRap": "795",
            "tenRap": "Rạp 5",
            "ngayChieuGioChieu": "2019-01-01T10:10:00",
            "giaVe": 75000,
            "thoiLuong": 120
          },
          {
            "maLichChieu": "33806",
            "maRap": "795",
            "tenRap": "Rạp 5",
            "ngayChieuGioChieu": "2019-01-01T12:10:00",
            "giaVe": 75000,
            "thoiLuong": 120
          }
        ],
        "url": "glx",
        "cinemaName": "GLX",
      }],
      "name": "Galaxy",
    }
  ];

  var flat = test.flatMap(item => {
    return item.cinema.flatMap(c => c.tickets);
  });
  console.log(flat);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
You can try this.
```

```js
var bookings = [
    {
      "cinema": [
        {
          "tickets": [
            {
              "maLichChieu": "19987",
              "maRap": "539",
              "tenRap": "Rạp 9",
              "ngayChieuGioChieu": "2019-01-01T10:10:00",
              "giaVe": 75000,
              "thoiLuong": 120
            },
            {
              "maLichChieu": "19988",
              "maRap": "539",
              "tenRap": "Rạp 9",
              "ngayChieuGioChieu": "2019-01-01T12:10:00",
              "giaVe": 75000,
              "thoiLuong": 120
            }
          ],
          "url": "cgv-1",
          "cinemaName": "CGV-1",
        }
      ],
      "name": "CGV",
    },
    {
      "cinema": [
        {
          "tickets": [
            {
              "maLichChieu": "33805",
              "maRap": "795",
              "tenRap": "Rạp 5",
              "ngayChieuGioChieu": "2019-01-01T10:10:00",
              "giaVe": 75000,
              "thoiLuong": 120
            },
            {
              "maLichChieu": "33806",
              "maRap": "795",
              "tenRap": "Rạp 5",
              "ngayChieuGioChieu": "2019-01-01T12:10:00",
              "giaVe": 75000,
              "thoiLuong": 120
            }
          ],
          "url": "glx",
          "cinemaName": "GLX",
        }
      ],
      "name": "Galaxy",
    }
  ];
console.log(bookings.map(s=>s.cinema).flat().map(s=>s.tickets).flat());
```